# how to get access to a prop from component in an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-props

i have to check the current Pathname of my website to set the Steps for my React-Joyride guided Tour.

i have a Parent Component where the routes are defined and in which the Joyride tour is implemented.
the Tutorial Component implements step Objects to set the steps for the tour like this:

```
import Tutorial from './tutorial/tutorial'
class App extends Component {
 constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state= {
    // state things 
    }
 }
  render () {
    return ( 
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Tutorial
          run={this.state.run}
          stepIndex={this.state.stepIndex}
          firstPartClicked={this.state.firstPartClicked}
          secondPartClicked={this.state.secondPartClicked}
          handleRestart={this.handleRestart}
          handleEnd={this.handleEnd}
          handleSteps={this.handleSteps}
          handleFirstPart={this.handleFirstPart}
          handleSecondPart={this.handleSecondPart}
          handleClickedFalse={this.handleClickedFalse}
          handleSetVisited={this.handleSetVisited}
          handleCheckTourDone={this.handleCheckTourDone}
        />
        // many other Routes 
        <Route
            exact path='/matches/:matchId/' render={(props) => {
              this.removeGlobalTimeRef()
              const matchId = this.props.matchId
              return this.checkLoginThen(this.gotoMatchDetails(props))
            }}
          />
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
    
export default App  



import matchSteps from '../tutorial/steps/matchSteps'
class Tutorial extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isUpdatet: false,
      steps: []
    }
  }
  
  callback = (tour) => {
    const { action, index, type, status } = tour

    if ([STATUS.FINISHED].includes(status)) {
      this.props.handleEnd()
      this.props.handleClickedFalse()
      if (this.props.location.pathname.startsWith('/matches/') && this.props.location.pathname.includes('sequence')) {
        this.props.handleSetVisited()
      }
    } else if ([STATUS.SKIPPED].includes(status)) {
      this.props.handleEnd()
      this.props.handleClickedFalse()
      this.props.handleSetVisited()
    } else if (action === 'close') {
      this.props.handleEnd()
      this.props.handleClickedFalse()
    } else if ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND].includes(type)) {
      const step = index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1)
      this.props.handleSteps(step)
    }
  }
  
  render () {
    let { steps } = this.state
    const pathname = this.props.location.pathname
    const siteSteps = [matchSteps, matchEditorSteps, matchEditorStepsOne, matchEditorStepsTwo,
      matchSequenceSteps, matchSequenceStepsOne, matchSequenceStepsTwo, matchSiteSteps, matchSiteStepsOne, matchSiteStepsTwo]

    for (let i = 0; i < siteSteps.length; i++) {
      if (pathname === siteSteps[i].onSite && siteSteps[i].part === 'full') {
        steps = siteSteps[i].steps
      } else if (pathname === siteSteps[i].onSite && siteSteps[i].part === 'one') {
        if (this.props.firstPartClicked === true) {
          steps = siteSteps[i].steps
        }
      } else if (pathname === siteSteps[i].onSite && siteSteps[i].part === 'two') {
        if (this.props.secondPartClicked === true) {
          steps = siteSteps[i].steps
        }
      }
    }
   }
   return (
      <>
        <Joyride
          callback={this.callback}
          run={this.props.run}
          stepIndex={this.props.stepIndex}
          steps={steps}
          continuous
          disableOverlayClose
          spotlightClicks
          showSkipButton
          locale={{
            back: <span>Zurück</span>,
            last: (<span>Beenden</span>),
            next: (<span>Weiter</span>)
          }}
          styles={{
            options: {
              primaryColor: '#2d98da'
            }
          }}
        />
      </>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Tutorial)



const matchSteps = {
  name: 'matchSteps',
  // onSite: '/matches/:matchId/',   <-- HERE 
  part: 'full',
  steps: [{
    target: '.row',
    title: '',
    content: 'bla bla',
    placement: 'center',
    disableBeacon: true
  }]
  
export default matchSteps
```

now i have to set the matchId in the step Object at `onSite: '/matches/:matchId/'` so i can check the pathname in the Tutorial Component.
i dont know how to do it correctly i've tested some ideas but the matchId was always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react router hooks [useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) to get the parameters of the current url

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

let { slug } = useParams();
```

or use react router hooks [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) to get the current url as [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) object

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

let location = useLocation();
```

Comment: thank you but the matchId is is always different depending on which game is selected. and i have to check if the current pathname matches the onSite prop.

Comment: I don't understand the but, can you explain? What is not suitable?

Comment: i'll try, the matchsteps is an object which is used in the Tutorial component to render the right steps for the page (onSite). And i need the matchId from Parent Component to declare the onSite path in my matchsteps. with that i can check in the Tutorial component if the onSite === pathname. i dont know if there is a better way. iam new in react and programming at all

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me. Well the question is clear but the code snippets are not.

There are only two data flows in javascript.  Data flows down from parent to child via properties. Data can be passed back to a parent via a callback.  You can chain that callback from child -> parent -> grandparent.

```
class grandparent extends Component {
   getDecentData = (data) => { do something with data}

   render(){
        <Parent CB = {this.getDecentData}/>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {

   render(){
        <Child CB = {this.props.CB} />
    }
}

class Child extends Component {

    clickHandler=(e) => {
       // do something to get data
       this.props.CB(data)
    }

   render(){
          <Control  onClick={this.clickHandler} />
    }
}
```

Comment: i used this for my functions to pass them throug the components but the matchSteps is an Object and not a Component so i don't know how to get access to the matchId

Comment: Its hard to follow all your code, would be better if you trimmed it to just the variables in question.  But i think your fundamental approach is wrong using a function that is setting variable to call back to a component. Where is match steps getting the matchId from?

Comment: currently matchsteps dont get the matchid thats my problem, i have to get access to the match id in the matchsteps object

Comment: Is this matchId present in the url at the time the component, where you need this value, is rendered?